# Why store table relations in a different table?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

I have seen people often use a separate table to store relations between tables.

Example,
Table Company_companys has two columns a nodeid which is a company id and a linkid which is a companyid of a different company.

Why do people do this when the same thing could be accomplished with an extra column in the Company table? Is is for performance reasons? or is there some other reason?

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers and examples, I understand now that in order to achieve First Normal Form when a many to many relationship is necessary, a separate table is needed to store the multiple links. When thinking about the above question I had pretty much forgotten the concept of many to many relationships so I was thinking about it from a one to many relationship point of view :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably because it's representing a **MANY TO MANY** relationship. With the approach you are mentioning, you only have a **ONE TO MANY** relationship.

So, in your example, if your tables semantic mean to represent any company probably relating to many other companies, you need a separate table for that.

Comment: But table Company could have a column called LinkedCompanys that is a string of company ids. Now each company in the Company table can link to many companys. Oh wait, I see, this would still be a one to many relationship but in what scenario would a many to many relationship actually be needed?

Comment: @toc777 you don't ever want to store a string of comma delimted values ina field. If you ever think of doing this, you need a related table.

Comment: Totally agree with @HLGEM. Besides, that is violating **First Normal Form** of relational data: each attribute **must store** only one value (From Wiki: *Every row-and-column intersection contains exactly one value from the applicable domain (and nothing else)*)

Comment: @HLGEM Your absolutely right, I should have thought about that before I posted it.

Comment: @Toc777 - A good example of many to many is employees working on projects.  There are 100 employees, and 50 projects, and 10 employees per project.  If you do this all in one table you will have 500 rows with repeating data such as project name, employee info, etc.  Or, you can do a list of projects, a list of employees, and then a relation table connecting them.

Answer (score 2):

The additional "link" table is required if you have [Many to many relationship](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is to resolve an issue with many-to-many (*..*) relationships.  Using a third table with foreign keys creates 2 one-to-many relationships as a many-to-many relationship is usually bad database design.